# Export SharePoint content to JSON

Tags: json, sharepoint

i would like to export the SharePoint content in JSON format. I would like to export all content within a farm, site, and so on.
What is the best way to do this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for a one-off export, or some API that exposes SharePoint content in JSON format?

Comment: Both solutions would be ideal! What do you suggest me?